# Calculate inverse of matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, adjoint-operators

If
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-19 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
how do I calculate $A^{-1}$? Is there any simple method other than reducing it to reduced row echelon form? By using cofactors and determinant?

Comment: There are lots of zeros in that matrix.  Perhaps you learned a way to simplify the computation in a matrix like this.

Comment: **Hint:** compute the determinant via blocks. $\det A = (-1)(-1)=1.$

Comment: hint: this is a block matrix. the inverse is in term of the inverse of the smaller matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a block-diagonal matrix with $2\times 2$ blocks: $\,\begin{bmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{bmatrix}$. It is invertible if and only if $A,B$ are invertible, and in such a case the inverse is $\,\begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} &0\\0&B^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$.

This being said, Gauß's method gives:
$$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 1\\-19&5\end{bmatrix},\quad B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-5 & 2\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: @Sebastiano:  Yes, of course. I'm waiting.

Answer (score 1):

**1. General method**:
You add an identity matrix and then transform your $A$ into an identity matrix, while simultaneously $I$ gets transformed into $A^{-1}$.
$$
\left(A | I\right) \to \cdots \to \left(I | A^{-1} \right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
 -5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-19 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
  1 & -1/5 & 0 & 0 &  -1/5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 &  1/5 & 0 & 0 & -19/5 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 &    0 & 1 & 2 &     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 &    0 & 3 & 5 &     0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
  1 &    0 & 0 &  0 &  -4 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
  0 &    1 & 0 &  0 & -19 & 5 &  0 & 0 \\
  0 &    0 & 1 &  2 &   0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
  0 &    0 & 0 & -1 &   0 & 0 & -3 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|cccc}
  1 &    0 & 0 &  0 &  -4 & 1 &  0 &  0 \\
  0 &    1 & 0 &  0 & -19 & 5 &  0 &  0 \\
  0 &    0 & 1 &  0 &   0 & 0 & -5 &  2 \\
  0 &    0 & 0 &  1 &   0 & 0 &  3 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

**2. Special case block diagonal:**
Using this special case of 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & B
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
we can apply this algorithm to the matrix blocks
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
 -5 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
-19 & 4 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 & -1/5 & -1/5  & 0 \\
  0 &  1/5 & -19/5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\to \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 &    0 &  -4 & 1 \\
  0 &    1 & -19 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and similar for the second block $B$.

**3. Special case $2\times 2$ matrix:**
Using this even more special case of $2\times 2$ blocks, one could use
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\Rightarrow
A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\alpha\delta - \beta \gamma}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\delta & -\beta \\
-\gamma & \alpha
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
This uses cofactors and determinant, by the way.

For example
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 5 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\Rightarrow
B^{-1} = \frac{1}{-1}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
 5 & -2 \\
-3 &  1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
-5 &  2 \\
 3 & -1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

Comment: take advantage of the block structure of $A$

Answer (score 0):

Reducing it to row-echelon form should be quite simple since you will only need to do two row-operations. You will find that $A^{-1}$ is of the same structure as $A$, that the non-zero entries are in the top left $2\times 2$ square and the bottom right $2\times 2$ square.

In general, if you have a matrix in block-diagonal form you only need to find the inverse for each of the blocks and assemble the inverses to form the inverse of the whole matrix.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $B,C,D,E$ are two by two matrices then

$$\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & C\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
D& 0 \\
0 & E\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
BD & 0 \\
0 & CE\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus
$$\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 \\
0 & C\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
B^{-1} & 0 \\
0 & C^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now use the formula for the inverse of 2x2.